# d3 multiline update path and transition path does not work with nested data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I want to update the circles and the paths in this graph with a transition. However it does not work.

I am not very experienced with D3. How can I make my code better? Changing data structure is no problem. I want bind the data to graph with exit() remove() and enter() without deleting whole graph and add the data every time I update again. I do not know how to use enter() exit() and remove() for nested data. One time for the whole group and the other side updating the circle and paths. The ID should be fixed.

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8) I have a little single line example from d3noob.

---

here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wj266kmx/)

```
var data = [{
    id: 'p1',
    points: [{
      point: {
        x: 10,
        y: 10
      }
    }, {
      point: {
        x: 100,
        y: 30
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 'p2',
    points: [{
        point: {
          x: 30,
          y: 100
        }
      }, {
        point: {
          x: 230,
          y: 30
        }
      },
      {
        point: {
          x: 50,
          y: 200
        }
      },
      {
        point: {
          x: 50,
          y: 300
        }
      },
    ]
  }
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var line = d3.line()
  .x((d) => d.point.x)
  .y((d) => d.point.y);

function updateGraph() {
  console.log('dataset contains', data.length, 'item(s)')
  var allGroup = svg.selectAll(".pathGroup").data(data, function(d) {
    return d.id
  });
  var g = allGroup.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "pathGroup")
  allGroup.exit().remove()

  g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return line(d.points)
    });

  g.selectAll("path")
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.points)
  });

  g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d => d.points)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("fill", "teal")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.point.x
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.point.y
    })
    .exit().remove()

}
updateGraph()

document.getElementById('update').onclick = function(e) {

  data = [{
      id: 'p1',
      points: [{
        point: {
          x: 10,
          y: 10
        }
      }, {
        point: {
          x: 100,
          y: 30
        }
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 'p2',
      points: [{
          point: {
            x: 30,
            y: 100
          }
        }, {
          point: {
            x: 230,
            y: 30
          }
        },
        {
          point: {
            x: 50,
            y: 300
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ];
  updateGraph()
}


$('#cb1').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    data = [{
        id: 'p1',
        points: [{
          point: {
            x: 10,
            y: 10
          }
        }, {
          point: {
            x: 100,
            y: 30
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        id: 'p2',
        points: [{
            point: {
              x: 30,
              y: 100
            }
          }, {
            point: {
              x: 230,
              y: 30
            }
          },
          {
            point: {
              x: 50,
              y: 200
            }
          },
          {
            point: {
              x: 50,
              y: 300
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    ];

  } else {
    data = [{
      id: 'p1',
      points: [{
        point: {
          x: 10,
          y: 10
        }
      }, {
        point: {
          x: 100,
          y: 30
        }
      }]
    }];
  }
  updateGraph()
});
```

Comment: You have a scope problem with `data`.

Comment: i just want that the graph updates with new data when clicking on update

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** to change the data join to be be appropriate.

I think the issue has to do with variable `data`. So, I added `data` as an argument to the function and specified separate names for different data sets. When I specify different data names, I'm able to update the chart:

```
var first_data = [{
    id: 'p1',
    points: [{
      point: {
        x: 100,
        y: 10
      }
    }, {
      point: {
        x: 100,
        y: 30
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 'p2',
    points: [{
        point: {
          x: 30,
          y: 100
        }
      }, {
        point: {
          x: 230,
          y: 30
        }
      },
      {
        point: {
          x: 50,
          y: 200
        }
      },
      {
        point: {
          x: 50,
          y: 300
        }
      },
    ]
  }
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var line = d3.line()
  .x((d) => d.point.x)
  .y((d) => d.point.y);

function updateGraph(data) {
  console.log('dataset contains', data.length, 'item(s)')
  var allGroup = svg.selectAll(".pathGroup")
    .data(data, function(d) { return d; });

  var g = allGroup.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "pathGroup")

  allGroup.exit().remove()

  g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        console.log("update path");
      return line(d.points)
    });

  g.selectAll("path")
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.points)
  });

  g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d => d.points)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("fill", "teal")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.point.x
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.point.y
    })
    .exit().remove()

}
updateGraph(first_data)

document.getElementById('update').onclick = function(e) {

  var update_data = [{
      id: 'p1',
      points: [{
        point: {
          x: 20,
          y: 10
        }
      }, {
        point: {
          x: 100,
          y: 30
        }
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 'p2',
      points: [{
          point: {
            x: 30,
            y: 100
          }
        }, {
          point: {
            x: 230,
            y: 30
          }
        },
        {
          point: {
            x: 50,
            y: 300
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ];

  updateGraph(update_data)
}


$('#cb1').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   var click_data = [{
        id: 'p1',
        points: [{
          point: {
            x: 10,
            y: 10
          }
        }, {
          point: {
            x: 100,
            y: 30
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        id: 'p2',
        points: [{
            point: {
              x: 30,
              y: 100
            }
          }, {
            point: {
              x: 230,
              y: 30
            }
          },
          {
            point: {
              x: 50,
              y: 200
            }
          },
          {
            point: {
              x: 50,
              y: 300
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    ];

  } else {
    var click_data = [{
      id: 'p1',
      points: [{
        point: {
          x: 10,
          y: 10
        }
      }, {
        point: {
          x: 100,
          y: 30
        }
      }]
    }];
  }
  updateGraph(click_data)
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wj266kmx/32/

Comment: that does not work. My Problem is to update the points when you click on the update button

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Take another look.